# Не работает цикл из-за Tkinter!

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как я понял, tk с циклами не дружит, т.к само окно (root, window...) по сути является циклом. Моя программа, которая должна выводить данные о процессоре, должна также выводить загрузку ЦП на ДАННЫЙ МОМЕНТ, т.е должен быть цикл обновления этих значений. Моя идея состояла в том, чтобы после кнопок и прочего добавить вот такой цикл обновления значения:

```
while True: # Цикл изменения параметров
    cpy_load_info.configure(text=str(psutil.cpu_percent())) # Возвращает нагрузку ЦП в виде float 
    time.sleep(1) # Задержка
```

Но когда я запускаю код, окно просто не появляется, а просто идет выполнение моего цикла. Что делать?

Comment: Это не цикл не работает из-за Tkinter, а Tkinter не работает из-за вечного цикла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def func():
    #ваши действия
    root.after(1000,func)

func()
```

функция которая вызывает сама себя через 1 секунду.
получается вечный цикл.1й раз её нужно запустить вручную.
`root.after` это штука ткинтера, внутри милисекунды и имя функции без ().

Comment: Дай я тебе руку пожму что ли